# Unable to browse songs from Media Server

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently working on UpnP project. I want to turn my iPod touch into Media Server (For ex: https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/arkmc-lite-dlna-upnp-media/id640095560?mt=8). So I have used the following SDK ([link](https://github.com/MediaBrowser/MediaBrowser.Plugins/blob/master/ThirdParty/UPnP/Platinum/README.txt)).I have integrated successfully and it is showing in the Media Servers list but when I click on the server it is unable to browse the media files. Could any one please let me know what my issue is? Thanks for your time

Here is some brief code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    upnp = [[PLT_UPnPObject alloc] init];

    // create server and add ourselves as the delegate
    PLT_MediaServerObject* server = [[PLT_MediaServerObject alloc] init];
    [server setDelegate:self];
    [upnp addDevice:server];
}

- (IBAction)performUPnPStarStop:(id)sender {
    if ([upnp isRunning]) {
        [upnp stop];
        [mainButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [upnp start];
        [mainButton setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}


#pragma mark PLT_MediaServerDelegateObject
- (NPT_Result)onBrowseMetadata:(PLT_MediaServerBrowseCapsule*)info
{
    return NPT_FAILURE;
}

- (NPT_Result)onBrowseDirectChildren:(PLT_MediaServerBrowseCapsule*)info
{
    return NPT_FAILURE;
}

- (NPT_Result)onSearchContainer:(PLT_MediaServerSearchCapsule*)info
{
    return NPT_FAILURE;
}

- (NPT_Result)onFileRequest:(PLT_MediaServerFileRequestCapsule*)info
{
    return NPT_FAILURE;
}
```

Also I am getting one message in log is **NEPTUNE_LOG_CONFIG not found in 'Info.plist'**

[image]

Comment: @vampirewalk I want to browse using the Network not using the MPMediaQuery. We can access using the Upnp with help of Network.

Comment: Yes you are right I want Local DMS and root paths

Comment: @vampirewalk I request you to read my question first and then give me your suggestions. The link you have given is already in my question.

Comment: I have clicked and it is same the difference is you have linked for different file not to the different project. If you click on the issues in the GitHub project there is one issue filed please check it

Comment: @vampirewalk I have tried all the ways but didn't work

Comment: @vampirewalk if you please do it for me I will give you 200 points for you as a bounty Thank you

Comment: I have finished this feature in my app.It can stream music in iPod library directly, also it supports seeking.

Comment: hey @vampirewalk can you please post the code?

Comment: No, I can't. It's commercial.

Comment: sorry if possible could you please tell me which SDK you have used?

Comment: @Tendulkar Hi friend, I had fun looking into your problem! What do you think of my solution?

Comment: Sorry @Drakes could you please give me some time in case if it resolves my issue definitely vote for you

Comment: No problem @Tendulkar, I hope this has helped you!

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I'm late to the thread. I took a look at the SDK source you supplied. I tried to hunt down what might cause this "800 Internal error". Here's what I found:

In `PltMediaServer.cpp` down around line 434 there is this bit:

```
if (NPT_FAILED(res) && (action->GetErrorCode() == 0)) {
    action->SetError(800, "Internal error");
}
```

so then what causes `NPT_FAILED(res)` to be `true`? I looked back in the source and found out that on line 424

```
res = OnBrowseDirectChildren(
    action, 
    object_id, 
    filter, 
    starting_index, 
    requested_count, 
    sort, 
    context);
```

but your code (and the default test code too!) has

```
- (NPT_Result)onBrowseDirectChildren:(PLT_MediaServerBrowseCapsule*)info
{
    return NPT_FAILURE;
}
```

and no other variant of `OnBrowseDirectChildren` that I can see from your code.

The default implementation of this is in `PltMediaServerObject.mm` on line 44:

```
NPT_Result OnBrowseDirectChildren(PLT_ActionReference&          action, 
                                      const char*                   object_id, 
                                      const char*                   filter,
                                      NPT_UInt32                    starting_index,
                                      NPT_UInt32                    requested_count,
                                      const char*                   sort_criteria, 
                                      const PLT_HttpRequestContext& context) {
        if (![[m_Target delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(onBrowseDirectChildren:)]) 
            return NPT_FAILURE;

...
```

So you avoid the failure condition there, but then this bit comes up on line 62:

```
NPT_Result result = [[m_Target delegate] onBrowseDirectChildren:capsule];
```

and that is where your `NPT_FAILURE` will be returned which will bollocks up the media browse.

---

There's another way this error could occur, on line 415 of `PltMediaServer.cpp` there is

```
res = OnBrowseMetadata(...);
```

but your code again is like this with no other variants.

```
- (NPT_Result)onBrowseMetadata:(PLT_MediaServerBrowseCapsule*)info
{
    return NPT_FAILURE;
}
```

and this will lead to a similar error condition.

---

So voilà, an explanation to why you are getting 800 Internal errors. My recommendation, implement them.

Here are sample implementations of said methods you can borrow or reverse engineer:

- https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/65353293/#l-1057
- https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/65652226/#l-1066
- https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/81801836/#l-1068
- https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/8307271/#l-1066
- https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/84764059/#l-556

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely implement your delegate methods (`onBrowseDirectChildren:`, etc.) in some useful way. E.g., for `onBrowseDirectChildren`, you should identify all the items that need to be returned in the response and build the response (a list of urls) with them.
Now, this goes well beyond what can be accomplished in an answer because of the many variables that are involved.

A good starting point for you would be adding the following log trace to, e.g., `onBrowseDirectChildren`:

```
NSLog(@"UPnP: Received Browse DirectChildren request for object %@, with sort criteria %s - count %d", info.objectId, info.sort, info.count);
```

Possibly, the best thing you could do is give a look at how XBMC implements [its own media server](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/master/xbmc/network/upnp/UPnPServer.cpp) on top of platinum.